# How to display JFreeChart in Java Swing GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfreechart

I want to create a graph using JFreeChart and display it in a java swing GUI. At the moment I have the following code to display it in a separate frame, please can someone help me out with the code I need in order to display it my GUI?

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
                "Title",
                "",
                "",
                myDataset,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false
                );

ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Results", chart);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little searching suggests that:

- A `JFreeChart` instance can also be added to a [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html).
- The `ChartPanel` extends `JPanel` so can be added to a `JFrame` (`JApplet`, `JDialog`, `JWindow`, `JPanel`, `JDesktopPane` ..).

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I go about setting a chart to be displayed in the ChartPanel though?

Comment: ChartPanel is component in the JFreeChart that you create an pass on the chart object. Afterwards you can use it as any other panel while adding to frame.